# Schema field is not being populated using mongoose populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my model:

```
const postSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  comments: Array
});

const Post = mongoose.model(“Post”, postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

Here is my code making a request to another microservice to populate the comments array, but it is empty, and is not being populated:

```
const UserPost = require(“./PostSchema”);

router.get("/post/list", async (request, response) =>{

try {
    let myUserPost = await UserPost.find();



    let postComments = await Promise.all(
        myUserPost.map((post) =>{
            
            axios.get(`${process.env.COMMENTS_MICROSERVICE_URL}/router/comments/list/comments/by/post/${post._id}`)
   .then((resp) => {
         resp.data.message.map((comment) =>{
    
                    
                    if(String(post._id) === comment.postID){
                        //console.log("post._id: ", post._id);

 /*** Desired, but does not work
    return UserPost.findById(post._id).populate('comments').exec();  */

 //The following alternative (embedding) works but adds the data to array
/***return UserPost.findByIdAndUpdate(post._id, {$addToSet: {"comments": comment}}, (err, data) =>{
err ? console.log(err) : console.log("aa: ", data);
     });   */  
                    }else{
                        console.log("no")
    
                    }
                    
                });
            })
            
        })
    );  

        
             

    return response.status(200).json({message: myUserPost});
}catch(err){
    return response.status(400).json({message: `${err}`});
}
});
```

What’s the best way to go about this and have it populate the comments field?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing the `ref` attribute from the model declaration:

```
const postSchema = Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'comments'
    },
    name: String,
    comments: Array
  });
  
  const Post = mongoose.model(“Post”, postSchema);
  module.exports = Post;
```

2. You should call `exec` after the `populate` method.

```
UserPost.findById(post._id).populate('comments').exec();
```

Comment: It’s Not being populated. No errors though.

Comment: The problem is how you are handling your `map` function. It's not clear what you want to achieve by mapping on the messages.

Comment: I want to map over the array of posts in the posts microservice and populate the comments array in the postSchema with the comments returned from axios network call that I’m making to the comments microservice.

Comment: You should handle the population on the backend. Can you post the middleware function handling the `/comments/list/:id` GET route?

Comment: I’ve updated my question with the full code. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `axios` from the backend to call a route declared on the same server. Can you post your `UserPost` schema declaration?

Comment: I’m making an axios call to the comments microservice. Note: Comments and posts are separate microservices. The UserPost schema is the schema posted in my question. I’m just importing it as UserPost.